# Wrong texturing with Mipmapping in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mipmaps

if I use this kind of mapping

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

my texture is working fine, but I want to get rid of pixel glitter effect like this

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

what I see is:
[image]

I tried with different sizes (1024x1024, 512x512, 256x256, 128x128, 64x64) with .jpg and .bmp and the effect is always something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your first version without mipmaps works and that you are using the same input data in both versions: The format parameter of `gluBuild2DMipmaps` is wrong. It seems you have RGBA data but tell OpenGL that it is RGB.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this difference. Of course it helped, thanks!